# Parent drop-down not appearing for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to create a custom post type that I can associate with parent posts (they are posts not pages). Wordpress is version 3.0.1. I was hoping to see a list of posts in a parent post drop-down under Page-Attributes but all I get its an 'Order' field. Have I missed something vital?

```
register_post_type( 'mytest_post_type',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'mytest Interviews' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'mytest Interview' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New mytest Interview' ),
                'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit mytest Interview' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New mytest Int.' ),
                'view' => __( 'View mytest Inteview' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View mytest Int.' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search mytest Interviews' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No mytest Interviews found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No mytest Interviews found in Trash' ),
                'parent' => __( 'Parent mytest Interview' ),

        ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author','custom-fields','page-attributes'),

    )
);
```

Or is it not possible to create a new custom post type and have those new posts be children of existing posts?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me. [Looking at the code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L535), the dropdown only appears if the post type is hierarchical (which is true in your case), and if there are other posts **of the same type** in the database. So a post can not be a child of another post type (a regular post or page for example), and the first new post of a type will not show the dropdown menu.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question, though it is not good news. I should look at the source more often. Busy day.....

Comment: @codecowboy: Why is this not good news? Did you want to combine posts of different types in one hierarchy? Perhaps that is possible with a minimum amount of work, you could ask a new question about it.

Comment: Yes. I've inherited a site with a strange and badly organised hierarchy. I want to combine posts of different types in one hierarchy but can't switch to page post-types.

Comment: @codecowboy: Interesting. Certainly worth a new question: "How can I combine posts of different type in one hierarchy?" The post listing would be a challenge, since WordPress normally shows posts per type.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you include this three property in your rregister_post_type argument

```
'supports' => [ 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail','custom-fields','page-attributes',  ],
'hierarchical' => true,
'capability_type' => 'page',
```